# Problem filtering 2 files using AWK for a given condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

First of all, thank you for your help. I have a problem filtering 2 files using AWK conditionals. The two files I want to filter are these one: Fasta.fa

```
>SiiA   lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111   100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169    99.048  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP009559.1_prot_WP_000389229.1_1106  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNNGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP029897.1_prot_WP_000389235.1_4284  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKIDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027  77.619  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
```

species_id (the file is larger and contain the name of different species)

```
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169`
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169
```

I want to use awk so it puts in fasta.fa the name of the species if both $2 in both files are the same in  so the output in a new file will be something similar as this:

```
SiiA    Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2 lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169 99.048  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
```

I have tried this two codes but none of them give the result I expect. Final file contains the same information as fasta.fa, so nothing has changed

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' species_id fasta.fa >> final
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $1 in a {$3=$4;$2=$3;$2=a[$1];$4=$5;$5=$6}1' species_id fasta.fa >> final
```

Comment: `if both $2 in both files are the same in so the output will be something similar as this:` could you please highlight the area which you want to match in 2 files, sorry but its not clear, thank you.

Comment: I have highlighted want I want from file 2 to be in file 1 taking into account $2 in both file have to match. I wish this clear you, thank you

Comment: Sorry but still not clear `Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis` part you want to match in both the files? But I can't see it in first file.

Comment: I only want to match the $1 in second file with the first file. As you can see both $2 in each file are the same structure. I want to put the name of the specie in the first file according to the relationship of the second file

Comment: Does your file actually have `**` as shown?

Comment: No @anubhava , I did it just because ravinder need it to see what I was selecting

Comment: As you can see @anubhava in fasta.fa in $2 we have lcl... and in species_id we have also lcl... Of course the files are much bigger, but I want to select the species that have the same lcl from species_id and insert it in its corresponding lcl in fasta.fa

Comment: I'm sorry @anubhava, the files are much bigger and contain more species name that you can't see, but what I am looking for is how to match them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231891/discussion-between-quik1399-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$2] = $1; next} $2 in map {$2 = map[$2] OFS $2; print}' species_id Fasta.fa

>SiiA Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
```